# How do I use VBA to fetch value from website?

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

Looking to create an excel VBA code that spits out a value that is stripped from a website. The website is https://www.peakhillcapital.com/dailybondyields/ and looking to pull the CMB 5-year value when I run the code.

I get the following error when I run the code:

> This Web query returned no data. To change the query, click OK, click the arrow on the name box in the formula bar, click the name of the external data range for the Web query, right-click the selection, and then click Edit Query.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ImportGoCYields()
    Dim webURL As String
    Dim webQuery As QueryTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    webURL = "https://www.peakhillcapital.com/dailybondyields/"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ws.UsedRange.Clear
    
    Set webQuery = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & webURL, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    
    With webQuery
        .Name = "CMB 5-Year"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
    End With
    
    webQuery.Refresh
    
    Set webQuery = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Data imported successfully!"
End Sub
```

Comment: alternatively https://greenbirchcapital.com/bond-yields/ can be used as well

Comment: In which line of code you take that message?